# Finding if two sets are equal

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have an formula

$(A\cap C) \cup ( B \cap  C) = C - ( A \cap B)$

and i have to prove if this equation is correct.
I transformed it into

$(\forall x\in U: x \in A \wedge x\in C) \vee ( x\in B\wedge x\in C) = x \in C \wedge ( x \notin A \wedge  x\notin B)  $

how could i further transform the equations in order to find if its true or not?

Comment: Two sets are equal iff they are the same set.

Comment: This hangs on the mathematical "or".

Answer (score 5):

A Venn diagramm might help here:

[image]

The sets do not overlap for $A \cap B \cap C$ and $C \setminus (A \cup B)$.

Comment: While the diagram is helpful , i am revising for test from Discrete math , we do have to use demorgan rules and so on in problems like this.

Comment: From the diagram you can infer that the equation is not correct. One approach to proof this is to state a counter example, an element for which the equation does not hold. The diagram gives you two subsets where you could prepare a counter example from.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think they're equal. Take $x$ such that $x$ belongs to all three sets $A,B,C$. Then $x$ is in the LHS but not the RHS.

Comment: Indeed. $C-(A\cap B)$ equals $(C- A)\cup (C-B)$ which is not equal to $(C\cap A)\cup (C\cap B)$ *except* when $ A=B^\complement $ .

Answer (score 2):

Instead of transforming the equation just go after the english meaning: those  in A and C or B and C are those in C but not both A and B. This is obvioyusly not true: Consider A=B

Comment: , i am revising for test from Discrete math , we do have to use demorgan rules and so on in problems like this.

Comment: @trolkura The tears of a stranger are just water. At any rate, you might be able to use my answer to help you create a counterexample you can check with DeMorgan's Laws.

Answer (score 2):

> I have an formula
>
> $(A\cap C) \cup ( B \cap  C) = C - ( A \cap B)$
>
> and i have to prove if this equation is correct. I transformed it into
>
> $(\forall x\in U: x \in A \wedge x\in C) \vee ( x\in B\wedge x\in C) = x \in C \wedge ( x \notin A \wedge  x\notin B)  $

Okay, firstly, this is a mishmash of concepts.   You don't want to use predicate logic, you want to reach for your *set builder notation* toolkit.   Related concepts to be sure, but not the same at all.

$$\{x\in U\mid (x\in A\wedge x\in C)\vee(x\in B\wedge x\in C)\}~=~\{x\in U\mid x\in C\wedge (x\notin (A\cap B)\}$$

Secondly, recall the deMorgan's Set Complement rules: $(A\cap B)^\complement = A^\complement\cup B^\complement$

$$\{x\in U\mid (x\in A\wedge x\in C)\vee(x\in B\wedge x\in C)\}~=~\{x\in U\mid x\in C\wedge (x\notin A\vee x\notin B)\}$$

Now just apply distribution to one side or the other to get them both in CNF or DNF form, as you prefer.   Then the verity of the statement should be apparent.